# Missing android.jar in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Today I opened the eclipse and there were errors all over the project. Right click on the project -> Build path and I see this:

[image: Missing android.jar]

How did this happen and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is the JAR in that path? If not, add it. If so, try `clean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found out the solution: 
 I opened up Android SDK Manager and I looked for the missing tools, which I installed from there. I don't know why my libraries got deleted, but I anticipate it happened while installing Android Studio or some update (for which I don't know).

Thank you guys for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Project File > Android Tool > Add Supporting Library